# Save meta box select value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, save, meta-boxes

I made a custom wordpress theme and on page it has he hero with a title and and background image but on some images the color of the title need to change from white to black. i'm trying to solve te problem with a meta box to allow me te switch from both colors depending on the image i use for the background.

The code that i'm using works good and I can see it only on the page template that uses the hero.

But  i've been trying to find a way to save the value of the meta box to use it in my theme for hours and i'm having a hard time finding a solution.

```
    // add meta box for boxed page template.

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_hero_meta');
function add_hero_meta()
{
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-templates/boxed-hero.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'page_hero-color', // $id
                'Hero Color', // $title
                'choose_hero_color_meta_box', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
                
        }
    }
}

// Display the post meta box.

function choose_hero_color_meta_box( $post ) { ?>

  <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'choose_hero_color_nonce' ); ?>

  <p>
    <label for="choose-hero-color" style="display: block;"><?php _e( "Select a color for the page hero display."); ?></label>
    <br />
    <select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select" style="width: 100%";>  
        <option value="dark" <?php selected( $selected, 'dark' ); ?>>Dark</option>  
        <option value="light" <?php selected( $selected, 'light' ); ?>>Light</option>
    </select>
  </p>
<?php }

// Save the value of the meta box
???????????? i'm stuck here
```

Comment: You have added this code to the page template, so it will appear for any pages that use the that template and will be saved on a page-by-page basis. I’m not sure what  If you have different hero images on different pages, this sounds like it is what exactly you need. If it’s working, I’m not sure what you are trying to do? Are you looking to set it once for the whole site? Then you need to add to the Customizer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. the code works good but i can't save the value of the select to use it in my template that's what i need. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I understand. I thought you wanted to add it in one place for the whole theme, which would be different. I’m only on my mobile now so I’ll take a look for you later.

Comment: Ok no worries, Thank you